# How to add single selection radio button on grid in gxt

Tags: radio-button, grid, gxt

In my application I have a grid which contains some rows.

In each row I want to put a radio button, and only one radio button can be selected in the grid (each row has one radio button).

To do this, I tried to add a GridCellRenderer and return a radio button using the following code :

```
GridCellRenderer<ModelData> button = new GridCellRenderer<ModelData>() {    
    @Override
    public Object render(ModelData model, String property,
            ColumnData config, final int rowIndex, int colIndex,
            ListStore<MonitorModel> store, Grid<MonitorModel> grid) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup();  

        for(int i=0; i<store.getCount(); i++){
            radio = new Radio();
            radio.setBoxLabel("radio"+rowIndex);     

            if(radio.getBoxLabel().equals("radio0")&& radio.getValue()== false){
                radio.setValue(true);   
                //isFirstTime = true;
            }
            radioGroup.addListener(Events.Change, new Listener<FieldEvent>() {
                public void handleEvent(FieldEvent fe) {                    
                    if (((Boolean)fe.getValue()) == true) {                     
                        radio.setValue(true);   
                    }
                }
            });         

        }       
        radioGroup.add(radio); 
        return radioGroup; 
    }         
};
```

When I load my grid, the result is correct.

But the problem I encounter is that when I click on a radio button, all the other radio buttons stay checked if they were already checked. How can I make that, when I click on a button, the others buttons are deselected ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should define the

```
final RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup();
```

As a class field, but **not in** the "**render**" method. Something like this:

```
GridCellRenderer<ModelData> button = new GridCellRenderer<ModelData>() {

    final RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup();  

    @Override
    public Object render(ModelData model, String property,
            ColumnData config, final int rowIndex, int colIndex,
            ListStore<MonitorModel> store, Grid<MonitorModel> grid) {

        for(int i=0; i<store.getCount(); i++){
            radio = new Radio();
            radio.setBoxLabel("radio"+rowIndex);     
    ......
```

Hope helpfull...

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, I have used following..

```
GridCellRenderer<ModelClass> button = new GridCellRenderer<ModelClass>() {    
        @Override
        public Object render(final ModelClass model, String property,
                ColumnData config, final int rowIndex, int colIndex,
                final ListStore<ModelClass> store, Grid<ModelClass> grid) {     
            Radio radio = new Radio(); 
            for(int i=0; i< store.getCount(); i++){
                radio = new Radio();
                radio.setName("Radio"+ i);
                radio.setHeight(16);

                if (model.get("checked").equals(Boolean.TRUE)) { 
                    radio.setValue(true); 
                } 
                else { 
                    radio.setValue(false); 
                } 
            } 
            radio.addListener(Events.OnClick, new Listener<FieldEvent>() {              
                @Override
                public void handleEvent(FieldEvent be) {                    
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // Something....
                }
            });
            return radio; 
        } 

    };
```

it works..